# How to set datetime Kind UTC for webapi url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{startDateUtc:datetime}/{endDateUtc:datetime}/{pageNumber?}", Name = "MyRoute")]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<string>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetData(DateTime? startDateUtc, DateTime? endDateUtc, int pageNumber = 1)
{
    HandleData(startDateUtc.Value, endDateUtc.Value, pageNumber);
    return this.Ok();
}
```

I try to use the following url: http://localhost:5555/MyRoute/2014-09-17T00:00:00Z/2014-09-18T00:00:00Z/1
The problem is that `startDateUtc.Value` and `endDateUtc.Value` have Kind `property = DateTimeKind.Local` .
I want to have dates in `DateTimeKind.Utc` Kind.

There are some solutions for example : apply `.ToUniversalTime()` function OR implement filter which will handle datetime params and call `.ToUniversalTime()`. But these are not good because I need to put these through all projects.

Is it possible to config it somehow in `Global.asax` OR implement some parser of datetime URL parameters which will based on exiting and just call for exmaple `.ToUniversalTime()` function?

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the kind UTC property to your dateTime

```
// Change the Kind property of the current moment to 
// DateTimeKind.Utc and display the result.

    myDt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(saveNow, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    Display("Utc: .............", myDt);

// Change the Kind property of the current moment to 
// DateTimeKind.Local and display the result.

    myDt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(saveNow, DateTimeKind.Local);
    Display("Local: ...........", myDt);

// Change the Kind property of the current moment to 
// DateTimeKind.Unspecified and display the result.

    myDt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(saveNow, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    Display("Unspecified: .....", myDt);
```

for you it should be like

```
[HttpGet]
  [Route("{startDateUtc:datetime}/{endDateUtc:datetime}/{pageNumber?}", Name = "MyRoute")]
  [ResponseType(typeof(List<string>))]
  public IHttpActionResult GetData(DateTime? startDateUtc, DateTime? endDateUtc, int pageNumber = 1)
  {
     HandleData(DateTime.SpecifyKind(startDateUtc.Value, DateTimeKind.utc), DateTime.SpecifyKind(endDateUtc.Value, DateTimeKind.utc), pageNumber);
     return this.Ok();
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, But this is the same like with using ToUniversalTime() function. I have about 20 other controllers and want to have the same behavior for these also. It means that I apply this fix for these other 20 controlles X 3-4 routes inside :) Too much work. Want to have one entry point for handling datetimes.

Comment: why don't you write a common method to convert it UTC just pass the Date Time there you convert to specific Kind.

Comment: Because then I need to paste this in all actions. And other developers who want to add new controllers need to do this. Ideally I want to built-in in parsing of datetime of URL and fix datetime OR if it exists using some flag for this. For example.. For JSON body parsing there is a flag: GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling . It would be cool if there is something the same for my taks.